# Python - How to defensively and logically program with noncompliant dataset - dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with dataset that uses a dictionary.  The data set is not guaranteed to be compliant for every part of it. Sometimes I received key errors or have nothing associated with the key.  What I can't figure out is how to deal with this problem. Because I come across this quite often. It causes me to defensively program on every line or step.  So what I want to know is how to deal with structurally and logically? What is confusing for me is. Should I use the dictionary default key and if there isn't a value, then default to false truth value which will follow with a if truth-value statement.  This seems very bulky and a lot of work to do this in every instance? Here is example of situation of working with my data structure.

## Bad item - No endtime key, no Name

```
job = {'name':'', 'starttime':, 'definition': [long list of stuff]}
```

## Good item

```
job = {'name':'name', 'starttime':5.5, 'endtime':6.5 'definition':
[long list of stuff]}
```

```
for job in batch:
            job_name = job.get('name', 'Error: No job name found!')
            start_time = float(job.get('starttime', 0.0))
            if start_time:
                current_runtime = time.time() - start_time
            end_time = float(job.get('endtime', 0.0))
            job_definition = job.get('definition', 'Error: No definition found!')
            parse_jobdef = parse_job_definition(job_definition)
            job_depends = parse_jobdef.get('depends', 'Error: No depends found!')

            average_runtime = get_average_runtime(job_name)
```

So if there is no name...then my program crashes. If not starttime, it could crash. If this is in iteration it doesn't mean that the whole program should crash but just on item is bad. I want to continue to next iteration.

This is more of generalize question and less of specific situation.

When dealing with data structure within iteration how deal with bad data? So missing keys and empty values. Should I just deal with the catching or if statement throughout my code. Is that the only way to deal with it?

Comment: If all you're going to do with the false value is print "error: no whatever found" and quit, then you may as well skip doing `get` at all, and just do `my_dict[key]`. This will make your program crash, sure, but from the point of view of the user, either approach is the same. They see an error message, and it stops working.

Comment: No thats not good. Because only that particular iteration is bad...the rest of the batch can be good and needs to be continued.

Comment: could you update the question with an example clean data and an example of the dirty data you see. highlighting which (is/are) the crucial key(s) that should not be missing.

Comment: I'm really asking for generalization of this type of situation not more for specfic code situation. I updated the code though.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely have to individually inspect each key for consistency to really solve the problem.  You may be able to compact some of this, like checking that a list of keys exist and are not empty, or are greater than zero.  However, depending on how thorough you need to be, you may need to check that values of specific keys are within a range or appear to be valid based on some number of criteria.  Whatever you do, replacing an invalid value with something like 0 needs to be done with extreme caution.  Most likely you are just corrupting your data and convincing the rest of your program that this data set is valid, when it's really just random default values.  If you find an inconsistency, you should probably just skip that record and use `continue` to move on.  To prevent unnecessary bulkiness, you can wrap everything inside your for loop in a `try` block, which prevents having to explicitly check if keys exist.

```
try:
    for need_not_empty_key in ["name", "start_time"]:
        if not job[need_not_empty_key]:
            #A required key is empty
            #Log the problem
            continue

    #Verify something about a specific key
    job_name = job["name"]
    if len(job_name) < 4:
        #Name is less than 4, it must be bad
        #Log the problem!
        continue

    #Rest of work here
    #Save results of this iteration here
except KeyError:
    #We must not have a needed key
    #Do some logging here instead of passing!
    pass
```

Comment: This what I asking for.  This conceptually solution to this problem. Ulitmately, theres a good solution, working solutions and bad solutions. I'm looking for good practice and principle and thought. Thank you.  Any further comments if needed would be great.

Comment: I added an example that will allow you to verify that keys exist and also that they are not empty or 0, with minimal bulkiness.  I also think it's reasonably pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this:

```
def has_keys(_dict, keys):
    for _key in keys:
        if not _dict.has_key(_key):
            logging.debug('{0} has no key {1}'.format(_dict, _key))
            return False

    return True



def your_function_where_you_do_stuff():
    ...
    _keys = ['name', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'definition', 'depends']
    for job in batch:
        if not has_keys(job, _keys):
            continue

        job_name = job[name]
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do:

keys = ('name', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'definition')

for job in batch:
  temp = dict.fromkeys(keys)
  temp.update(job)

This way you would always have all the keys you need, the missing one would have a None value.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_fromkeys.htm

(Sorry I'm on my phone)

Comment: I usually prefer making sure what I need is present by doing like above than testing if it is. It is often faster and easier to handle.